# npm failing to install packages with local dependency

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am having problems installing an npm package that has a [file dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) off of github. When installing directly from a local package there are no problems.

The package that I am trying to install has a dependency on a package defined within on of its subdirectories.

The error I am getting is as follows:

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
>
> npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules/local-dependency-example/local-dependency" as it does not contain a package.json file.

I created the following package in order to reproduce: https://github.com/eladzlot/local-dependency-example

In order to reproduce you should create an empty package: `npm init`.
Then attempt to install: `npm install eladzlot/local-dependency-example --save`.

This problem occurs both with npm v3.10.10 and npm v5.5.1

Comment: I have the exact same issue as you. I opened an [issue on NPM repo](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1756), maybe go give it a :thumbup:.

Comment: FWIW, this is fixed with NPM v7.